# Manipular elementos HTML usando Angular 7

Tags: html, html5, angular, typescript

¿Cómo manipular los elementos HTML utilizando angular 7?

Por ejemplo, obtener el tamaño de la ventana del navegador y asignar su tamaño a un div mostrando un mensaje con el alto y ancho del div.

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ejemplo',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
export class EjemploComponent {

  alto:any;
  ancho:any;

  constructor() {
    this.getTamanos();
  }

  //Evento para obtener el tamaño de la ventana del navegador
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) getTamanos(event?) {
    this.alto = window.innerHeight;
    this.ancho = window.innerWidth;

    //A partir de aquí se le asignarían los mismos tamaños de la venta al elemento div
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto te puede ayudar

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `
  <div [style.width]="width" [style.height]="height" style="background-color: teal;">
  <p>width: {{ width }}</p>
  <p>height: {{ height }}</p>
 </div>
`,
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'windows-event';
// si pones esta valor en 0 el valor del div sera el mismo que el de la ventana.
margin = 20;

width: string;
height: string;

constructor() {
  this.resizeDiv();
}

@HostListener('window:resize')
resizeDiv(): void {
  this.width = window.innerWidth - this.margin + 'px';
  this.height = window.innerHeight - this.margin + 'px';
}
}
```